# Model averaging parameter estimates for glmer models using AICmodavg in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, model-averaging

I encounter the following error trying to calculate model-averaged parameter estimates across a set of GLMM models using the AICmodavg package version 2.3.1. in RStudio(version1.2.5)

**ERROR:
Error in fam.link.mer(i) : object 'fam.type' not found**

My code:

`modavgShrink(cand.set = all.glmer[cand.models], parm = "Nosocomial")`

where all.glmer is a list of models and 'cand.models' specifies which models to choose. However, the error persists regardless of which models are assessed.

**all.glmer was derived as follows:**

`all.glmer <- lapply(all.mods, glmer, family = binomial, nAGQ = 0, data,control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))`

Example model from candidate list

The most complicated model in all.glmer looks like this (notice family and link are reported):

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Adaptive Gauss-Hermite Quadrature, nAGQ = 0) [glmerMod]

*Family: binomial ( logit )*

Formula: cbind(Resistant, NotResistant) ~ 1 + Nosocomial + Commensal +
Zoonosis + Humantransmission + NaturallyCompetent + Bactericidal.Static +
Pathogentype + TransmissionType + ResearchEffortPath + AntibioticDate +
ResearchEffortAntibiotic + EnvrionmentalReservoir + DrugUseTotal +
Conjugation + (1 | PathogenName) + (1 | Antibiotic) + (1 | DrugClass) Data: ..3 AIC BIC logLik deviance df.resid 56958.03 57052.34 -28459.02 56918.03 805

Random effects: Groups Name Std.Dev. Antibiotic (Intercept) 1.138
PathogenName (Intercept) 1.635
DrugClass (Intercept) 1.020

Number of obs: 825, groups: Antibiotic, 53; PathogenName, 49; DrugClass, 15

Fixed Effects: (Intercept) Nosocomial
34.40415 2.03080
Commensal Zoonosis
-0.24809 0.15806
Humantransmission NaturallyCompetent
1.26669 0.35246
Bactericidal.StaticBacteriostatic PathogentypeGramnegative
-0.59356 0.60654
PathogentypeGramPositive PathogentypeOther
1.93226 2.94426
TransmissionType ResearchEffortPath
1.84446 -0.58498
AntibioticDate ResearchEffortAntibiotic
-0.02170 -0.24500
EnvrionmentalReservoir DrugUseTotal
0.12931 0.58973
Conjugation
-0.02277

I do not understand why I get the error. **Why is AICmodavg unable to pull out fam.type?**

Thank you

Amrita